# SQL delete rows when no more row on other table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger on phpmyadmin.
I want to delete all rows from table `NEXT_GAME` as soon as there is no more row in `WAITING_ROOM`.

I tried the following solution :

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_begin_date AFTER DELETE
ON NEXT_GAME FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM WAITING_ROOM) THEN
        DELETE FROM NEXT_GAME;
    END IF;
END
```

I got the following error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a specific delimiter to tell MySQL that the next `;` doesn't ends the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER delete_begin_date AFTER DELETE
ON NEXT_GAME FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM WAITING_ROOM) THEN
        DELETE FROM NEXT_GAME;
    END IF;
-- vv----------------------- Notice this
END$$
DELIMITER ; -- switch back to the regular ;
```

Comment: Note that this has do be done for `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `CREATE FUNCTION` too